# I want to trigger a function if the characters in a textfield are equal to some number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger the following function only if the character count in textfield is equal to 8 else I will do something else. Below is the code I am using, Payment.php has the code for querying data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#item').keypress(function (event) {      
    var key = event.which;
    if (key == 13) {
        var item = $(this).val().trim();
        if(item.length == 8){

            var item = $('input#item');
            if (item != ''){            
                $.post('ajax/Payment.php',{user:item}, function(data){
                    $('div#test').append(""+data+"</br>");

                });
            };
        };
    else {
       // my code 
    };
};
});
}):
```

Comment: And the problem is.... ??? Your code looks right with your requirements

Comment: The only thing that makes no sense is this: `var item = $('input#item');if (item != ''){`

Comment: Currently you're also checking for `key == 13`, which is the `enter` key. You could combine the two if-statements to get one `else`. As it is your `else` is unbalanced.

Comment: use alert() or console.log() for triggering

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude This I was using to check if textfield is empty then nothing happens.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I will check that.

Comment: @Anant  I will try that and the enter key code will be inside this.

Comment: @Halcyon I did not get that

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by removing a line from the code.

```
var item = $('input#item');
```

Now I am getting the correct values.

Comment: Also one thing currently you code will running on each key press? isn't it?

Comment: Not on each key stroke. It depends when I press enter.

Comment: oh you misunderstood. you event `keypress` event runs every-time and check that enter is pressed or not? if yes then further codes will run

Comment: so after each character is typed it checks whether enter is pressed or not.

Comment: you said this `I want to trigger the following function only if the character count in textfield is equal to 8` so according to this your code is not processing.

Comment: well yeah you are right, but it does not matter. As I will have fix character input which is 8 or 13. So now I can easily use if else statement to make it work.